# How to open several folder in navigation sidebar SublimeText2

Tags: sublimetext2, sidebar

It's seems i can open only one folder in the navigation sidebar in the SublimeText2 editor.
Everytime i try it open a new window...i try using a widows with 2 layout and 2 group... and also " add folder to project".. same result.

Is there a way cause i need for example the package folder

`/usr/lib/python2.7/mypackage`

and the project folder in my `/home/project`

One way would be opening the top level directory... but it  not the best.

Give thanks to the community

Comment: Stock ST2 doesn't do this; it should work just fine. At the least, `Add Folder to Project` should allow you to add as many folders as you want. You may have a plugin or package installed that's changing how things work.

Comment: stupid thing !! it works perfectly by dragging the folder from the file manager...